# Llamar a la función de un padre. Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Llevo poco con React y todavía no comprendo bien cómo llamar a una función que reside en un componente padre.

Tengo dos componentes, un padre `App.js` y un hijo `Login.js`. Quiero que el hijo tenga un botón que llame a una función del padre.

¿Como puedo llamar a `botonClick` desde el hijo?

Componente padre:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.botonClick = this.botonClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      estadoLogin: true,
    };
  }

  botonClick(event) {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      this.setState({
        estadoLogin: false,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Componente hijo:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.botonClick = this.botonClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cuadrado">
        <div className="formulario">
          <span class="cabecera">
            <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
          </span>
          <input
            placeholder="Usuario"
            class="input"
            ref={this.usuarioElement}
          />
          <br />
          <label>Password: </label>
          <input
            placeholder="contraseña"
            class="input"
            ref={this.passElement}
          />
          <button onClick={this.botonClick}>Entrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para pasar una función a un componente hijo, puedes hacerlo mediante [`props`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
Si tu componente hijo es un componente Clase, puedes invocar una función utilizando `this.props.nombreDeLafuncion`

Si en cambio, tu componente hijo es un componente funcional debes suplementar a `props` como argumento del componente para poder acceder a ello, y luego usar `props.nombreDeLafuncion`:

```js
class Hijo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.botonClick}>
        Boton del hijo clase
      </button>
    )
  }
}

function HijoFuncional (props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.botonClick}>
      Boton del hijo funcional
    </button>
  )
}


class Padre extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.botonClick = this.botonClick.bind(this)
  }


  botonClick() {
    console.log('apretaste el boton!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Como pasar props</h1>
        <Hijo botonClick={this.botonClick} />
        <HijoFuncional botonClick={this.botonClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}




ReactDOM.render(<Padre/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una manera de hacerlo es pasar el método del componente padre como una propiedad mas, es decir en tu componente padre tendrás algo así:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Login onLogin={this.botonClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Y luego simplemente en tu componente hijo lo recoges mediante las props.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.props.onLogin}>Entrar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

al final hice eso. No conocía muy bien cual era la sintaxis exacta para hacerlo.

Padre:

```
botonClick(event){ 

}
    render(){
               return (
                 <div>
                    {this.state.estadoLogin ?
                      <Login botonClick={this.botonClick}  />:
                      <Vista2 />
                    }
                  </div>  
               );
      }
```

Hijo:

```
 <button onClick={this.props.botonClick}>Entrar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por contestar